# Is there a way to get same encrypted hash value with some secret key?

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I want to encrypt sensitive data in an encrypted format and save it to db. But later I have to be able to decrypt with a secret key used to decrypt. Importantly, encryption must give always the same hash.

```
const algorithm = 'aes256';
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
const key = crypto
  .createHash('sha256')
  .digest('base64')
  .substr(0, 32);

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
const encrypted =
  cipher.update(String('tobeEncrypted'), 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');

console.log(encrypted); 
console.log(encrypted); 
//e08f733a4dace8b22db763cbd2d0029e
//90086251f083c33dd6aa017a2c6f35f4

// How can I always get the same hash value?
```

Comment: Please put the original code, cause this code is wrong. createHash takes an algorithm not some secret key or something.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty sorry forgot, fixed it.

Comment: You will not meet your requirement of having the same hash for each ciphertext of equivalent plaintext. You’re literally encrypting the data with an `iv` value made up of 16 random bytes each time. If you need these hashes to align that badly, you need to go back to the drawing board on your design of this mechanism. If they did match up every time the same plaintext is passed I t would be a relatively weak algorithm vulnerable to known plaintext attacks.

Comment: What is the question here? `encryption must give always the same hash.` **Encryption is not hashing!**

Comment: You are using a fixed and known key. This doesn't really add much security at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your key will be the same `key` value. Because the value to be hashed will be empty.

```
const key = crypto
  .createHash("sha256") // Hash algorithm
  .update(process.env.SECRET_KEY) // Data to hash
  .digest('base64')
  .substr(0, 32);
```

Your result will be **always different** because the **IV** is random in each execution. So, you could store the `IV` in the database, in the final message, or use a unique depending on other values like the key or the data.

There is no security risk if you save the `IV` in your database or if you expose it.

Refs:

- [Is it safe to store AES IV prepended to CipherText in a DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586440/is-it-safe-to-store-aes-iv-prepended-to-ciphertext-in-a-db)
- [When using AES and CBC, is it necessary to keep the IV secret?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/when-using-aes-and-cbc-is-it-necessary-to-keep-the-iv-secret)

Comment: However, using the same fixed key every time is completely insecure. It's a strange design that uses a random IV but a fixed key.